# How to modify innerHTML/DOM of an HTML element in a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dom

I am trying to dynamically create a picklist in a lightning component which aligns with the lightning design system look and feel. The lightning design system says that we should create it as given in link below.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#flavor-picklist

I want to add list item elements from the helper on the fire of init method. I am receiving these items as a response of an apex controller call from the helper. However, when I am trying to modify the innerHTML of the list and add the response items as list items it is not rendering them.

I am doing it like

```
    var action = component.get(ApexCall);
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {

        var family=actionResult.getReturnValue();
        var famLength=family.length;
        var listDOM = document.getElementById("familyList");
        var j= listDOM.innerHTML;
        j=j+'<li id="menu-40-0" class="slds-dropdown__item"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio"> <p class="slds-truncate">';
        j=j+'<c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>'; 
        j=j+family[0]+'</p> </a> </li>"';
```

Could anyone tell me how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lightning I would be much more inclined to create this list through an `aura:iteration` at the component markup level, bound to an array that you can set, rather than appending strings to `innerHTML`. However if you still want to do it this way...

The `innerHTML` property is a string, not a reference. You are assigning it to a variable, building it up and then never sending it back. (Unless you have left out part of your code?) So try...

```
    var family=actionResult.getReturnValue();
    var famLength=family.length;
    var listDOM = document.getElementById("familyList");
    var j= '';
    j=j+'<li id="menu-40-0" class="slds-dropdown__item"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio"> <p class="slds-truncate">';
    j=j+'<c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>'; 
    j=j+family[0]+'</p> </a> </li>"';
    listDOM.innerHTML += j;
```

Also if you are not familiar with the shorthand increment/concatenation operator `+=`, in JavaScript `j = j + (expression)` can be written more compactly as `j += (expression)`.

Also be aware that inserting `c:svg` into the markup is probably not going to work because Lightning XML is converted to scripted elements at the server level and not at the browser level.

So what would a more data-based Lightning solution look like? Well in your markup you could have something like:

```
<aura:attribute name="family" type="String[]" />

<ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.family}" var="item">
        <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio">
               <p class="slds-truncate">
                   <c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>
               {!item}
               </p>
           </a>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

And then your controller would simply populate the array:

```
component.set('v.family', actionResult.getReturnValue());
```

Or merge the new items into an existing array, creating a new one if none is there:

```
var family = component.get('v.family') || [];
var newFamily = family.concat(actionResult.getReturnValue());
component.set('v.family', newFamily);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Charles. I realized the mistake in my design right after i posted this and shifted to aura:iteration. Worked perfect. However, the issue I am facing now is that I need the get the value of that {!item} on click of each <li>. Any idea how I can make that happen? I am not being able to do that since I don't have an ID and i guess lightning doesn't allow parameters on a client side controller.

Comment: Good question... one possibility is to assign an index variable as well (so `<aura:iteration items="{!v.family}" var="item" indexvar="index">`) and then tag the list item with a data attribute such as `<li class="slds-dropdown__item" data-index="{!index}">`. Your handler can then peek into the event and get the index out as `e.target.dataset.index`. Under Lightning Locker this works as long as the element was created in your namespace. (Not sure if there is a better way to pass up a parameter...)